# How to load external JS libraries for the whole project

Tags: html

How do you load an external library so that it is available all over the project?Say for example I have the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../public/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome core CSS -->
    <link href="../public/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is a test</p>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../jsLib/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So this includes the jQuery, Bootstrap, font-awesome and my personal stylesheet as you can see.

Question: What if someone goes to another page in my site for instance: /profileSettings.html

Will I have to load all the libraries again?

Sorry if this is a simple question but I am completely new to front-end development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course you have - that “other page” is a separate HTML document, and as such it needs to embed those external resources itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code grows in size, you'll start using more sophisticated frameworks that may use something along the line of an MVC setup. Some of these frameworks allow you to define multiple "views"(think of them as HTML files **for now**) that are called from a single HTML file(say the index file).

For those aware of AngularJS, i'm referring to writing Angular UI views and the `<ui-view>` tag.

This will allow you to have your dependencies in a single file, and the other pages just load from this page.

**More importantly.** 
I'm surprised noone has mentioned the use of `require-js` or other loaders.
It's particularly useful in cases where you have multiple JS dependencies, and multiple controllers in javascript.

Definitely check out loaders such as [require-js](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Thanks mate! Understood very well

Answer (score 0):

Each page is completely independant of every other page.

If you want a script to run on any given page, it has to be explicitly loaded into that page.

Comment: But I will be using these libraries on all pages. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: HTML generation by preprocessing templates. JS concatenation. JS minification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. U have to include the required lib in each file if it is normal file without any framework.

Comment: So if I wanted Bootstrap/AngularJS on all pages, I will need to call them in each and every file?

Comment: In Angularjs , U can include files which contains all javascript libraries `ng-include='externalLib.html'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the scriipt in every page because even thought it is a website, every page works seperately from another. All you need is a `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't that very inefficient? That's actually what I thought but then thought "hey, it can't be like that" lol.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, if you look each page as separate page. You need to include it in every page.

But if you have a master page, then we can inherit the same from master page so, no need to add the Codes/Script again.

**A cool option.**

Load one JavaScript file (JS File) for every page. Then load all the JS File using that JS File as you like.

**Example**

```js
var Device = {
    Device_Type: 'Desktop',
    //Scripts to be loaded in master page
    Common_Scripts: [
     '/SiteAssets/Bar.js',
      
    ],
    //CSS to be loaded in master page
    Common_CSS: [
      
     '/SiteAssets/nav.css',
     
    ],
    //to get device type
    Get_Device_Type: function () {
        var Getdevice = detect.parse(navigator.userAgent);
        if (Getdevice.device.type != null) {
            Device.Device_Type = Getdevice.device.type;
            Device.Process_Device_Files(Device.Device_Type);
            Device.Process_Common_Files();
            Device.Process_Common_Scripts();
        } else {
            console.log("Detected Device type :" + Device.Device_Type)
        }
    },
    //to load device based css files
    Process_Device_Files: function (File_Type) {
        File_Type = File_Type.toLowerCase();
        $('head').append(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" title="' + File_Type + '" href="announcement.css">'
  );

    },
    //To load css files to be loaded in master page
    Process_Common_Files: function () {
        _.each(Device.Common_CSS, function (eachfile) {
            Common.appendfile("css", eachfile);
        });

    },
    //To remove previously loaded device files
    Remove_Device_Files: function () {
        $('link[title="tab"]').remove();
        $('link[title="Mobile"]').remove();
        $('link[title="desktop"]').remove();
    },
    //To load scripts to be loaded in master page
    Process_Common_Scripts: function () {
        _.each(Device.Common_Scripts, function (eachfile) {
            Common.appendfile("script", eachfile);
        });
    },
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Render device based files')
    Device.Remove_Device_Files();
    Device.Get_Device_Type();
});
```

**Usage**

(Copy the Above code after Example until usage and paste it into a notepad and save it as device.js. Then include to the page. Then add the necessary JS to this codes. Sample files are already in the codes)

// Dependencies 
https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js?files=1